# Restrict access to web service to only allow mobile clients

Tags: ios, web-services, security, authentication

I'm currently building a mobile application (iOS at first), which needs a backend web service to communicate with.

Since this service will be exposing data that I only want to be accessed by my mobile clients, I would like to restrict the access to the service.

However I'm in a bit of a doubt as to how this should be implemented. Since my app doesn't require authentication, I can't just authenticate against the service with these credentials. Somehow I need to be able to identify if the request is coming from a trusted client (i.e. my app), and this of course leads to the thought that one could just use certificates. But couldn't this certificate just be extracted from the app and hence misused?

Currently my app is based on iOS, but later on android and WP will come as well.

The web service I'm expecting to develop in nodejs, though this is not a final decision - it will however be a RESTful service.

Any advice on best practice is appreciated!

Comment: I'd go the certificate route... But really any determined hacker could reverse engineer that or spoof user agent strings to appear as a mobile device, etc.

Comment: Exactly my thought - this doesn't really prevent anyone from accessing my service. I just thought with all the apps out there today, that some sort of best practice had evolved and I just didn't know about it. I guess all I can do is make it a little more difficult - but then, why even bother when the determined hacker (who would probably even be the only one going through the work of identifying my service behind the app) easily can gain access...?

Comment: SSL based communication + public key signing = pretty solid communication

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but if you could get the MAC of the sending device, you could possibly categorize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: You cannot prevent just anybody from acecssing your web site from a non-mobile client. You can, however, make it harder.

Easy:

- Send a nonstandard HTTP header
- Set some unique query parameter
- Send an interesting (or subtly non-interesting) User Agent string
- (you can probably think of a few more)

Difficult:

- Implement a challenge/response protocol to identify your client
- (Ab)use HTTP as a transport for your own encrypted content
- (you can probably think of a few more)

Of course anybody could extract the data, decompile your code, replay your HTTP requests, and whatnot. But at some point, being able to access a free Web application wouldn't be worth the effort that'd be required to reverse-engineer your app.

There's a more basic question here, however. What would be the harm of accessing your site with some other client? You haven't said; and without that information it's basically impossible to recommend an appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you Matthias for you very thorough answer! The app is basically a sort of shopping app, where the service exposes available offers, and the app consumes and present these to the end-user. My reason for restricting access is to 1) keep competitors from scrapping my offers, and 2) avoid people with bad intentions from tampering with my analytical data, since every request to the service will be kept for various analytical purposes (which in this case could be a valuable asset).

Comment: Scraping (not scrapping) or similar activities are not a mobile-vs.-whatever problem.

You should add code to detect these activities on the server side. For instance, normal users don't click ten offers per second and they tend to go through your site in somewhat-topical, not random or depth- or breadth-first, order.

You might also want to raise the bar for access to your site (email registration, a captcha).

Comment: I agree - this sort of detection mechanisme is probably the most useful solution to my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes--sounds like some sort of server-side anti-spoofing heuristics may be your best bet.